# getMonth dentro de un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo un histórico de los últimos 6 meses y no sé como ponerle el getMonth (número de mes actual) y meses anteriores (-1, -2...) para que me devuelva el mes actual y los 5 meses anteriores:

```
var monthsArray = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];
```

Después tengo para mostrar los nombres de los meses:

```
var historyData = [
    {
        month: 0,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: 1,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: 2,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: 3,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: 4,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: 5,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    }]
```

La fila "MONTH" como puedo hacer que sea con un getMonth equivalente al mes actual? Si le pongo los números tengo que estar cambiándolo cada mes, con lo que si con el getmonth lo puedo automatizar mejor que mejor. Gracias.

Comment: No termino de entender el problema, si quieres obtener el mes actual deberías usar [`Date`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: Tampoco entiendo ¿Qué representa `month`? ¿Un número de mes, una cantidad de meses hacia atrás, u otra cosa?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas el objeto Date, leer el mes y restarle de 0 a 5 para tener los seis últimos meses.
Mira el ejemplo, para ver que funciona el cálculo de meses

```js
var monthsArray = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];
console.log("actual "+actual)
for(i=0; i<6; i++){
  console.log(monthsArray[(new Date().getMonth()-i+12)%12]);
  }
```

Como ves obtienes los seis últimos meses desde el actual .
El mes actual lo obtienes de la fecha del día con **new Date()**
De ese valor obtienes el mes con getMonth() eso te da un índice del mes actual (van de 0 a 11).
Los seis meses anteriores lo obtendrías restándole de 0 a 5.
Pero si estás en Marzo los meses anteriores pueden salir negativos:
Marzo es el mes 2 (van desde 0) si le restas 3 tienes -1, que se debe corresponde con Diciembre (índice 11).
Para convertir los negativos en índices válidos del mes se usa la operación resto.
La conversión de índices también la puedes hacer con una función, lo mismo lo ves más claro. Pero en una línea lo resuelves.
Tus objetos quedarían

```js
var historyData = [
    {
        month: (new Date().getMonth()-5+12)%12,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: (new Date().getMonth()-4+12)%12,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: (new Date().getMonth()-3+12)%12,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: (new Date().getMonth()-2+12)%12,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: (new Date().getMonth()-1+12)%12,
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    },
    {
        month: new Date().getMonth(),
        total: 0,
        rentals: 0,
        packs: 0,
        pases: 0,
    }]
    
    console.log(historyData[2].month)
```

Te lo dejo así desarrollado porque no se como es el contexto de la página y además queda más claro. Está claro que en lugar de -5+12 pondrías +7, pero está explicitado por cuestión de claridad.
Lo normal en estos casos es usar un bucle e ir asignando a cada item el mes. Puedes usar el bucle del primer ejemplo.
Esto para no complicarse demasiado. También podrías crear un objeto con un método para ajustar la propiedad month, por ejemplo.